# Python changing array to String containing array when making value in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I get an array of strings from an external call. I then pass that array of strings to a class `__init__` function, then set the value in a dict to be that array. When I look at the value in that array, the value of the dict which should be an array is now a string containing the array. I put a `print()` statement in the `__init__` to make sure the value was an array when inside the function but changes when accessing it after

For example: `["abc", "123", "def", "456"]` turns into `"["abc", "123", "def", "456"]"`

Here's a snippet pf my code:

```
class PersonReference:
    def __init__(self, uid, uniqueIds):
        self.uid = uid
        self.personState = {'uniqueIds': uniqueIds}
```

Comment: It sounds like the API is returning JSON, and you're not converting it to a list.

Comment: Python won't turn the list into a string by itself. So it must already be a string.

Comment: `print()` doesn't show the quotes around a string, so you can't tell the difference by putting `print(uniqueIds)` in the function.

Comment: "I put a print() statement in the init to make sure the value was an array when inside the function" Did you realize that when you `print` a string, it won't show quotes around the outside or escaping (that's the *purpose* of `print`)? So, if a string happens to start with an open square bracket and end with a close square bracket, etc., it could look identical to a list when printed. You should use a more accurate test. The built-in `type` function can tell you the type of objects, for example.

Comment: You can also use the built-in `repr` function (or the `!r` format code) to try to represent the objects more faithfully when printed. Oh, while we're on the topic: we call them *lists*, not arrays.

Comment: Finally, as a side note for the future: please don't tell us about your level of experience. To the extent that it matters, we can tell; giving a reminder is *at best* a distraction, and at worst makes you keep thinking of yourself as a beginner, which makes it harder to improve. Please keep in mind that one of the main goals of Stack Overflow is to make questions useful to *others, much later in the future*, who find the question with a search engine. They are not going to care about your life.

Comment: oh I see that the `type` function is either `str` or `NoneType` when called (since I need to create a list of these objects). is there some functionality to help me convert a string that looks like an array to an array?

Comment: What you've got is a json string, and you should use `json.loads(...)` to convert it.  Under no circumstances should you consider `eval`.  You would be opening a massive security hole in your program.

Comment: @FrankYellin that worked! thanks a bunch!